# how to get value by reference of count using java

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

```
    public boolean addPeerReview(String courseid, String studentname, String ratings, String feedback, String reviewerName) {

    boolean flag = false;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into PEERREVIEW (courseid,studentname,ratings,feedback,reviewerName) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, courseid);
        pst.setString(2, studentname);
        pst.setString(3, ratings);
        pst.setString(4, feedback);
        pst.setString(5, reviewerName);
        if (i <= 2) {
            if (pst.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                flag = true;
                i++;
            }
            else{
            flag=false;
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Above is my code.I call it in this servlet(basically this adds records to DB)

```
int count =0;
 if(peerreview.addPeerReview(courseid, studentname, rating, feedback, reviewerName)){

        message = "Peer review successfull!";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("peerreview.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        count++;

    }
```

I want only two records to be added to the database(the scenario is students should be able to do a peer review for two other students).Therfore,i am using a count, however when i run the method again,since java is pasing by value and not reference the count always starts from 0 when i call the method again,instead of starting from 1.Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using :

```
static int count
```

*The static modifier is used to create variables and methods that will exist independently of any instances created for the class.*

*All static members exist before you ever make a new instance of a class, and there will be only one copy of a static member regardless of the number of instances of that class.*

*In other words, all instances of a given class share the same value for any given static variable.*